# How to jit a python code with a third-party library by numba?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm working on a project which uses Pyquante2. Its speed must be boosted. To do that, I'm trying to write  jitclass. Here is the code

```
import time
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from numba import njit, jit, float64 
from pyquante2 import basisset, molecule, uhf, rhf, onee_integrals, contourplot

spec = [('int1',int64),('int2',float64),('int3',float64)]
        
#,('h2',float64[:]),('bfs',float64[:]),('solver',float64[:]),('ens',float64[:])
        

@jitclass(spec)
class hfock(object):
     
    def __init__(self):
        self.int1 = 1
        self.int2 = 0.00000000 
        self.int3 = 0.36628549
    
    @property
    def mol(self):
        h2 = molecule([(self.int1, self.int2, self.int2, self.int3), 
                       (self.int1, self.int2, self.int2, -self.int3)], 
                        units='Angstrom')
        return h2
    
    def bs(self):
        bfs = basisset(self.h2, 'sto3g')
        return bfs
    
    def rhf(self):
        solver = rhf(self.h2, self.bfs) 
        ens = solver.converge
        return ens
```

However, it gives this error

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'molecule': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "numbatrial.py", line 29:
    def mol(self):
        h2 = molecule([(self.int1, self.int2, self.int2, self.int3), 
        ^

During: typing of get attribute at <string> (3)
During: typing of get attribute at <string> (3)
```

What should I do to solve this problem? I've been working on it for days. I checked so many topics and forums. Also, I checked the manual section of numba site. However, no answer gives a satisfying help so far. I need obvious and brief solutions rather than vague and complicated ones.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible (fundamentally unsupported by Numba). But you can use PyPy if the module is supported (eg. written in pure python).

Comment: It is written in both Python and C. Also, it must be supported by Numba since it fundamentally uses numpy quite much. So, if it is what you meant, it must be possible somehow. Otherwise I have to find another way to boost it because PyPy isn't working too.